# Bulk "open with" change on OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, file-association

I use Microsoft remote desktop to connect from my mac to the windows machine I work on. I have a directory with about 50 different rdp files. (The config files for each machine). They go changed to open with the remote desktop in Windows XP on Parallels.

Is there a command I can use to change all those back to opening with the remote desktop on my Mac?

I can use the right mouse click "Always open with" command, or the equivalent on the "Get Info" menu, but I would like to find a way to make that change in bulk. "Change All..." button on the "Get Info" menu does not have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, this may help :

> Upgrade Parallels to the latest 5626
>   build via the "Check for updates"
>   option under the "Parallels Desktop
>   "Help" menu.
>
> Turn on SmartSelect in the Shared
>   Applications options in Configuration
>   Editor and start Windows.
>
> Go to the Applications menu and choose
>   the "SmartSelect - Set to default"
>   menu option to recreate file
>   associations.
>
> After that click one of the buttons
>   ("Only for this VM" or "For all VMs").

Comment: Is upgrading Parallels the only way to fix this? I was not planning on upgrading to version 5, I did not think it was worthwhile.

Comment: Just an idea... but I gave up the ghost on Parallels a while back..and 
now use Sun's Virtual Box -- since it's free.

Comment: I would need to purchase a new Windows license I think. Worth trying I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this for several dozen shell scripts used to launch rdesktop via X11.app.

My solution was to select all the files, right click -> "open with -> Other...", then select the appropriate app and hit "always open with".  That opened a couple dozen RDP windows, which I closed, but it did take mass effect permanently.  I found your question while looking for a better way.  At least what I did is better than selecting each individual file.